# Using Lambda functions in Delphi

Tags: delphi, lambda

I have a question about lambda function.

In example below  the code it is a lambda function in Delphi?

```
var
  Lambda: TFunc<Integer, Integer>;
begin
  Lambda:= function(ANumber: Integer) : Integer
           begin
             Result:= ANumber * ANumber;
           end;


   ShowMessage(Lambda(2).ToString());
   ShowMessage(Lambda(4).ToString());
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. What do you think a lambda function is? What doubts do you have about this function regarding whether it fits what you believe the definition to be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Delphi terminology that is an anonymous function. In some languages they are known as Lambda functions. So yes, this is a Lambda function.

This is Wikipedia's take on the subject: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function

Comment: In Delphi context I would not call them lambdas (although they could be called like that) because in C# for example there is some huge difference between a lambda function and a normal anonymous method: a lambda function can be compiled to an expression tree that can be read and evaluated.

Comment: @Stefan That's a C# detail that doesn't apply to Delphi. So I see no reason not to use the lambda term in its generic CS form. It would be very nice if we could write anon/lambdas without all that blasted boilerplate.

Comment: Embarcadero nowhere uses the term lambda function in their doc but always calls them anonymous methods so I would stick with that name and not use the term lambda function to avoid the confusion I explained above.

Comment: @Stefan As I read the question, lambda is used in a generic cs context here

Comment: Lambda functions are "basically" anonymous methods internally, but what makes it be called lambda it's because it contains just the mathematical (data) operations and not programming keywords. This exemple should be something like: Lambda := X => x * x;
We don't have Delphi syntax for it, but, yes, now it looks a mathematical operation, so a lambda. That yes, internally it's a anonymous function that received X and multiple X per X and return it.
But, no, looking for this verbose and nom mathematical keywords, a pure anonymous functions is not considered a lambda.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino I don't think that's correct. I'm not aware of any widely accepted definition of lambda that says it is a function composed only of mathematical operations. The accepted definition is that lambda function and anonymous function are synonyms and refer to a function that is not bound to an identifier.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino And that is a widely accepted view is it? Anyway, leaving the issue of names aside, I'd like you to back up this idea that a lambda is something that "does not have programming keywords". I think you are making more of this than there really is. If you don't like my answer, downvote it and feel free to add another.

Comment: To add my two cents (and apart from the wikipedia definition which mixes things up). IMHO the biggest difference between a _lambda_ and _anonymous_ function is that the former can access the context of the caller  whereas anonymous functions happen to be only functions with no name. And this ability to access the parent context is the biggest strength of lambdas, so for example you can run a loop like (in pseudocode): `a = 5; bigger_list = a_list.foreach(x : x * a);` whereas with anonymous function you would need to write: `a = 5; bigger_list = a_list.foreach(x : x * 5);`

Comment: @Jacek not sure if you are talking about Delphi, but there, anonymous functions definitely CAN use context of caller (http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/anonymousmethods_xml.html#416E6F6E796D6F7573204D6574686F6473205661726961626C652042696E64696E67)